# How to get primary replica info for the SQL availability group by powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I want to get the machine of current primary replica in Powershell. Is there cmdlet to do it?

I load sqlps module and dump the find all *sql* command, but seems no one is related to this..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo");

$svr = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("AServerInstanceInYourAG");

$svr.AvailabilityGroups["YourAvailabilityGroup"].PrimaryReplicaServerName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the Primary Replica by connecting to the listener

```
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo");

$listenerName = "YourListenerName";

$sqlListener = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($listenerName);

$primaryReplicaName = $sqlListener.AvailabilityGroups.PrimaryReplicaServerName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the owner name property from the cluster resource name:

```
get-clusterresource -name $AGName |  Select -ExpandProperty OwnerNode
```

Below is an example I use to copy SQL agents from one node to another:

```
$Node1 = 'Node1\Instance1'
$Node2 = 'Node2\Instance2'
$AGName = "AG_Name"

$AGPrimary = get-clusterresource -name $AGName |  Select -ExpandProperty OwnerNode  
If ($AGPrimary -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME)
{
Copy-DbaAgentJob -source $Node1 -destination $Node2  
write-host 'Success!'
}
else
{
    Write-Output "No object copying is processed, this is not the primary node."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, it is still useful almost 3 years later

Today, it is much easier to answer the question

```
import-module sqlserver;
$svr = "svr_name" # this can be any server involved in Availability Group
$AGPath = "sqlserver:\SQL\$svr\default\AvailabilityGroups";
dir -path $AGPath | select-object Name, PrimaryReplicaServerName;
```

This will return the AG name and the primary replica server name